# How to show an Attribute table in the Store of the WSO2 GREG?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I added a new attribute in the soap service artifact that store unbounded operations of the service (it's like the table of contacts or endpoints)

My question is how to show that attribute table in the Store?

I tried edditing the asset-attributes.hbs putting the new attribute like this

```
<div class="es-col-lg-12 col-lg-12">
    <h4>{{t "Operaciones del Servicio Web"}}</h4><hr>


    {{#each this.attributes.operaciones_nombre }}


    <div class="es-col-lg-12 col-lg-12 divrow">
        <div class="col-lg-2"><b>{{t "Nombre"}} :</b></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">{{ this.attributes.operaciones_nombre}}</div>
    </div>

    {{/each}}
```

But the problem is that it doesnt show the *this.attributes.operaciones_nombre* when it's inside of the *#each*, even when i used *this.attributes.operaciones_nombre.[0]* to show only the first element

And why the loop only work with *{{#each this.attributes.operaciones_nombre }}* and not *{{#each this.attributes.operaciones }}*? Do I need to define it in the asset.js and how I do that?

Comment: Are you using 5.2.0? does below answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

for contacts use this. I tested below code for restservice and its works fine. for endpoints and for your case you can use the same.

In the relevant **asset.js** add below **asset.renderer**,

```
asset.renderer = function (ctx) {
    return {
        pageDecorators: {
            jsonFormatter: function (page) {
                if (page.meta.pageName === 'details') {
                    var contacts = page.assets.attributes.contacts_entry;
                    if (contacts) {
                        var contacts_entry = [];
                        if (contacts.constructor === Array) {
                            for (var index in contacts) {
                                var contact = contacts[index].split(':');
                                var contact_entry = {};
                                contact_entry.name = contact[0];
                                contact_entry.value = contact[1];
                                contacts_entry.push(contact_entry);
                            }
                        } else {
                            var contact = contacts.split(':');
                            var contact_entry = {};
                            contact_entry.name = contact[0];
                            contact_entry.value = contact[1];
                            contacts_entry.push(contact_entry);
                        }
                        page.assets.attributes.contacts_entry = contacts_entry;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Note: if there is already pageDecorators defined here, separate those methods using a comma and add above method.

In the **asset-attributes.hbs** add below lines,

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Contacts</h4><hr>
        <div class="col-lg-12 table table-striped table-hover divrow">
            {{#each attributes.contacts_entry}}
            <div class="col-lg-2">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">{{value}}</div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note: In your asset extension you need to have **asset-attributes.hbs**(/{GREG_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/assets/{SHORTNAME}/themes/store/partials/asset-attributes.hbs) file overriding the default file which is located in **greg-store-defaults**.

Please find the sample screenshots of publisher and store,

**Publisher**

[image: Pub view]

**Store**

[image: store view]

Note: there are some alignment issues. CSS/bootstrap!  ;)

Please refer [this blog post](http://niranjankaru.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-extend-assets-store-view-in-wso2.html).

Note: next time please add the rxt definition for the relevant attribute as well.

Comment: Thanks!. But I dont undersantd this part  _var contacts = page.assets.attributes.contacts_entry;_.Should I put _page.assets.attributes.operaciones_entry_ (Doesnt work, tested it)? Where is this _entry_ came from?

Comment: @Daniels did you try it out first? 
BTW tested and working fine, attached the screenshots as well. :)

Comment: As far as I understand for your case it should be, 'page.assets.attributes.operaciones_entry'